# How to optimize this my mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing a new project. I need a help for the mysql query, I think it is very slow.

```
SELECT post_id, user_id, content, title, TIME, (

SELECT username
FROM users
WHERE id = posts.user_id
) AS username
FROM posts
WHERE user_id =1
OR user_id
IN (

SELECT DISTINCT user_to
FROM friends
WHERE user_from =1
OR user_to =1
)
ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The second part starting with ``OR user_id IN ( ... )`` is probably the cause of your performance issues. Try eliminating it just to see how fast the query is without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.user_id, p.content, p.title, p.TIME, u.username
FROM (select distinct us.* 
      from friends f
      join users us on f.user_to = us.id
      WHERE f.user_from =1 OR f.user_to =1) u
JOIN posts p on u.id = p.user_id
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT a.post_id, a.user_id, a.content, a,title, a.TIME, b.username
FROM posts a
INNER JOIN users b
ON a.user_id = b.id
WHERE a.user_id =1
OR a.user_id
IN (

    SELECT DISTINCT user_to
    FROM friends
    WHERE user_from =1
    OR user_to =1
)
ORDER BY a.post_id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

This should be faster than your actual query.

Comment: +1 you can take it a step further and instead of `DISTINCT` you can use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY NULL` to prevent mysql to use filesort

Comment: Unfortunately, i get an DB Exeption: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b.id WHERE a.user_id = 1 OR a.user_id IN ( SELECT DIST' at line 4 [ SELECT a.post_id, a.user_id, a.content, a,title, a.TIME, b.username FROM posts a INNER JOIN users b ON a.user_id b.id WHERE a.user_id = 1 OR a.user_id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT user_to FROM friends WHERE user_from = 1 OR user_to = 1 ) ORDER BY a.post_id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0 ]

Comment: @user2473500 my bad, sorry it was missing an equal, please check it now

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
SELECT  
    p.post_id
  , p.user_id
  , p.content
  , p.title
  , p.`time`
  , u.username
FROM posts AS p
/*LEFT*/ JOIN users AS u ON u.ID = p.user_id
WHERE user_id = 1
    OR user_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT user_to
        FROM friends
        WHERE user_from = 1
          OR user_to = 1
    )
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```